# Duplicate values returned on SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: psql

I'm getting duplicate values returned when I do an inner join to the change_management table. it returns three records but I only want the most recent cmp.id.

```
SELECT
 cmp.id,
 cr.id,
 coalesce(cmp.effort, 0.00) AS "Effort"
FROM
 m_change_request cr
 INNER JOIN (select max(id) as id, change_request_fk, effort from m_change_management group by id, change_request_fk, effort) as cmp ON cmp.change_request_fk = cr.id
WHERE
 cr.release_fk=509
```

I need it to return the most recent record by max(cmd.id). Any ideas how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
SELECT    
 cmp.id,     
 cr.id,
 cr.number AS "PSL #"
FROM
 m_change_request cr
 LEFT JOIN m_change_management cmp ON cr.id = cmp.change_request_fk
 LEFT JOIN m_change_management cmp2 ON cr.id = cmp2.change_request_fk AND cmp.id < cmp2.id
WHERE
 cr.release_fk=509 AND cmp2.change_request_fk IS NULL
```